# How to get json data in AJAX success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my AJAX code to fetch dropdown record.

```
function item_value() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (json) {
      if (json == '') {
        alert('No Records');
      } else {
        alert(json);
        $.each(json, function (index, elem) {
          $("#item_select1").append("<option value=\"" + elem.value+ "\">" + elem.name+ "</option>");
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

This file is used to pull record or get get records in AJAX success.

**Ajax.php**

```
<?php
include('../dbconnection/comp_connect.php');
$qry_item="SELECT item_id,item_name,item_unit,rate,description,tax_id,status FROM item";
$view_item=$conn->prepare($qry_item);
$view_item->execute();
$rs_item=$view_item->fetch((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
$data = array('item_name' =>$rs_item['item_name'],
              'item_unit'=>$rs_item['item_unit'],
              'rate'=>$rs_item['rate'],
              'description'=>$rs_item['description'],
              'tax_id'=>$rs_item['tax_id']
             );
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: how about you send a json header with php?

Comment: So you have some code. Did you have a question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (What problem are you having? What have you done to debug it? What error messages are you getting? Do you ever know where to look for error messages? What do the raw HTTP requests and responses that you are getting looking like? etc. etc.)

Comment: Have you parsed the response JSON http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: @ravisachaniya — Yes, they have. You can see they have. It's in the code: `dataType: "json",`

Comment: maybe log `json` and get the output.

Comment: what is the output of `$rs_item` ? and also `$data` does not contain `value` and `name`

Comment: is there any need for this `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the data that you're creating in PHP doesn't line up with what you're trying to do in your AJAX success function. The PHP code fetches *one* row from your database, so the JSON it will return will look like:

```
{
    "item_name": "something",
    "item_unit": "something",
    "rate": "something",
    "description": "something",
    "tax_id": "something"
}
```

But this part of your success function

```
$.each(json, function (index, elem) {
  $("#item_select1").append("<option value=\"" + elem.value + "\">" + elem.name + "</option>");
});
```

needs an collection of objects (`elem`) with `name` and `value` properties. Instead, with what you're getting from PHP, each `elem` will be a string or number, so `elem.value` and `elem.name` will be undefined.

Since you're using this to append options to a select, your PHP needs to return multiple rows, and the keys you assign in PHP need to match the properties you refer to in your success function. Something like this should be closer to what you want.

```
<?php
include('../dbconnection/comp_connect.php');
$qry_item = "SELECT item_id, item_name FROM item";
$view_item = $conn->prepare($qry_item);
$view_item->execute();
while ($item = $view_item->fetch((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = ['value' => $rs_item['item_id'], 'name' => $rs_item['item_name']];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In you php script make sure to add following headers before you print our the encoded data

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```